# Node.js + Express.js access result of db.collection

Tags: database, node.js, express

I am just starting out with node.js and express.js and have a little questions I hope someone can answer.

Within my route I have the following code

```
router.get('/:slug', function(req, res) {
 var subject = req.params.slug;
 var subjectTitle ='';
 var db = req.db;
 db.collection('subjects').findOne({slug:subject}, function(err, result) {
   console.log(result);
   console.log(result.title);
   subjectTitle = result.title;
 });

 res.render('subject', { title: subject});
});
```

I dont understand how I can access the result of the db call outside of the function that calls it.

Ideally I want to send result.title back as the subject into the render call.

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: db.collection is async function call, you should put the `res.render('subject', { title: subject});` into `function(err, result){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.

```
router.get('/:slug', function(req, res) {
     var subject = req.params.slug;
     var subjectTitle ='';
     var db = req.db;
     db.collection('subjects').findOne({slug:subject}, function(err, result) {
       console.log(result);
       console.log(result.title);
       res.render('subject', { title: result.title});
     });

    });
```

Comment: This is called  closure. If you define a function inside a function it has the parent scope.